# How to prevent any execution until got response from server in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-services, synchronous

I am very new to Angular and my requirements are like below.

**A** is a function in **Service** which returns true or false

**B** is a function in **Component** which excepts a values from service.

```
function A()
{
    isSuccess: boolean = false;
    //logic
    if (err) 
    {
       this.isSuccess = false;
    }
    else 
    {
       this.isSuccess = true;
    }
    return this.isSuccess;
}

function B()
{
    var obj = new Service();
    var ret=obj.A(); 
}
```

here value of "ret" in function B is always false. It is because it return false from function A before we receive response from server.

**Actual Example**

***upload.service.ts***

```
export class S3FileUploadService 
{
   isSuccess: boolean = false;
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   uploadFile(file: File, bucketName: string, fileName: string): boolean 
   {
      debugger;
      const contentType = file.type;
      const bucket = new S3(
      {
         accessKeyId: '<accessKeyId>',
         secretAccessKey: '<secretAccessKey>',
         region: '<region>'
      });
      const params = {
         Bucket: bucketName,
         Key: fileName,
         Body: file,
         ContentType: contentType};


      bucket.putObject(params, function (err: any, data: any) {          
         if (err) 
         {
            this.isSuccess = false;
         }
         else 
         {
            this.isSuccess = true;
         }

    });
    return this.isSuccess;
  }
}
```

***upload.component.ts***

```
var isSucess=this.uploadService.uploadFile(file, this.bucket, file.name);
if(isSucess){
   //further logic of component
}
```

Here before call back function get executed it returns false to component. But after 3 to 4 second  it goes into call back function and set it to true. But it was too late because component logic already got executed.

I have also used promise() and then(). but no luck.

**Update**

***tried with promise***

*service*

in same function i used putObject method like below

```
return await bucket.putObject(params).promise()
```

*component*

```
this.uploadService.asynchUploadFile(file, this.bucket, file.name).then((data) => { 
      if (!data.$response.error) {
        this.IsSuccess=true
      }
      else
         this.IsSuccess=false
})
```

Comment: This is classic case of using Observable. There's a lot of online material. You can start here: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

Comment: First you should get to know the basics, how async code works, what are promises, the basic concept. There's a tutorial I suggest: https://javascript.info/async
After that it's easier to understand how rxjs works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not return with `isSuccess` which is a boolean property, but `Promise` or `RxJS#Observable`. In the code where you call the `uploadFile` you can handle the callback with `.then()` if you returned a promise, or `.subscribe()` if you chose observable.

I don' know for sure what S3 is, but as I search for it you may be using Amazon's aws. The `S3` instance has a `promise` function, you should return that.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

You should treat your `isSuccess` property in your component as a 3 state value. The inital value could be `undefined` which identicates you are waiting for result, after in your then callback you assign the value to it. Or you can introduce an another property like `isPending`,  set it true before you call the service, and set it back to false in the callback.

You should do this in your service:

```js
export class S3FileUploadService 
{
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   uploadFile(file: File, bucketName: string, fileName: string): boolean 
   {
      const contentType = file.type;
      const bucket = new S3({
         accessKeyId: '<accessKeyId>',
         secretAccessKey: '<secretAccessKey>',
         region: '<region>'
      });
      const params = {
         Bucket: bucketName,
         Key: fileName,
         Body: file,
         ContentType: contentType
      };
      return bucket.putObject(params).promise()
  }
}
```

After that you can do this in your component:

```js
...

this.uploadService.uploadFile(file, this.bucket, file.name).then((data) => { 
  this.IsSuccess = !data.$response.error;
  // Do all data related stuff here.
});

// No other code should be written here.
```

Comment: Please check the updated question. I used promise as well but compiler did not stop on then block. it executes all other code and after some time "Then" block executed.

Comment: So i could put all the remaining code in "Then" block and everything will be working fine. but question is, it will work like call back function, so what's diff. between promise and callback function?

Comment: Well it's not so much different, but it's more readble and you can use async/await with a promise. With that you can almost write it as first. https://javascript.info/async-await#await

Comment: The problem is that your `uploadFile` will return before the callback function in your service. It will chanege the `IsSuccess` of your service, but in another context, somewhere in the future.

Answer (score 1):

@Aijaz here is a working demo that illustrates a very similar scenario. Based on Observables: https://angular-ivy-dgzmep.stackblitz.io.

The service provides this functionality that demonstrates a lengthy API call:

```
  getWithSuccess(): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(true).pipe(delay(3000));
  }
```

The component calls this service as follows:

```
this.success$ = this.myService.getWithSuccess();

this.success$
.pipe(tap(response => console.log(response)))
.subscribe();
```

Same for failure so you can see both scenarios.